# Few Applications in Program Files(x86) couldn't start

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, application-launch

While starting a few application on my Laptop I get an error dialog saying: Windows cannot find 'address/to/exe/file'.

I am attaching two snips of two different applications. They were working fine. I have been having this issue in one of the application for about a month. I thought something was wrong with the application but now I am having issues with one more application

[image: Error Dialog]

[image: Error Dialog]

Comment: Do these files exist at those locations?

Comment: Yes they do exist. I tried launching it from the location still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. The problem has nothing to do with the two application. It's a bug in recent updates in windows. Follow these steps:

```
1. Click your Start Button, type regedit and hit Enter to open the Registry Editor

2. Click View and make sure 'Address Bar' is turned on

3. Paste this into the Address Bar at the top and hit Enter

4. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Option

5. In the left pane, right click and delete the folders of the apps/games that don`t work
```

Comment: [Those instructions appear to have be written by someone else.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-cant-run-certain-programs-because-it-cant/df892bed-2af4-4805-8cdc-d02efe9c3f5f).  Please properly cite your source